# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent. Query is not working well

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Please help. I have query where I need to search with price - currency ($cur) in DB I have **daily_price, hourly_price and currency** (GEL, USD). I have written this Eloquent query:

```
if($request->input('currency') == 'USD'){
        $query->where(function ($qu) use ($request) {
            $qu->where('currency', 'USD')->where(function($q) use ($request){
                $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')]);
                $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')]);
            });
        })->orWhere(function ($qu) use ($request, $cur) {
            $qu->where('currency', 'GEL')->where(function($q) use ($request, $cur){
                $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))*$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))*$cur]);
                $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))*$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))*$cur]);
            });
        });
    }else{
        $query->where(function ($qu) use ($request) {
            $qu->where('currency', 'GEL')->where(function($q) use ($request){
                $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')]);
                $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')]);
            });
        })->orWhere(function ($qu) use ($request, $cur) {
            $qu->where('currency', 'USD')->where(function($q) use ($request, $cur){
                $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))/$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))/$cur]);
                $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))/$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))/$cur]);
            });
        });
    }
```

the code starts with this query: `$query->whereIn('city_id', $arr);`

I don't have anything on `city_id = 5` in my DB, but when I add my currency query it gets me some (I think random) result of rows... Please help.

Comment: Please paste the whole code that builds the query along with what you're getting in the request.

Comment: the whole function is this: http://pastebin.com/3aDvAECL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

```
if($request->input('currency') == 'USD'){
        $query->where(function ($que) use ($request, $cur) {
            $que->where('currency', 'USD')->where(function($q) use ($request){
                $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')])
                    ->where('daily_price', '>', 0);
                $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')])
                    ->where('hourly_price', '>', 0);
            });

            $que->orWhere('currency', 'GEL')->where('daily_price', '>', 0)->where('hourly_price', '>', 0)->where(function($q) use ($request, $cur){
                $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))*$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))*$cur])
                    ->where('daily_price', '>', 0);;
                $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))*$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))*$cur])
                    ->where('hourly_price', '>', 0);
            });
        });
    }else{
        $query->where(function ($quer) use ($request, $cur) {
            $quer->where(function ($que) use ($request, $cur){

                $que->where('currency', 'GEL')->where(function($q) use ($request){
                    $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')])
                        ->where('daily_price', '>', 0);
                    $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [$request->input('priceFrom'), $request->input('priceTo')])
                        ->where('hourly_price', '>', 0);

                });

                $que->orWhere('currency', 'USD')->where(function($q) use ($request, $cur){
                    $q->whereBetween('daily_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))/$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))/$cur])
                        ->where('daily_price', '>', 0);
                    $q->orWhereBetween('hourly_price', [((int)$request->input('priceFrom'))/$cur, ((int)$request->input('priceTo'))/$cur])
                        ->where('hourly_price', '>', 0);
                });

            });
        });
    }
```